Regarding the use of the term messiah
I would like to know if I can use the term messiah in regards to a savior or a heroic person. An example is me writing a book about this savior who comes and saves this nation and their football club and wins them the world cup or someone who saves his people from villains. I know the term messiah means anointed one referring to isa PBUH. But they English dictionary has multiple terms for the meaning of messiah and in Islam it's about your intentions. I don't mean to compare isa and some fictional character. In English messiah can mean someone who's a hero or does something great for his people

You should be careful, as of your own understanding, that word as a combination of letters triggers very different thoughts in people, depending on their background. If you are a writer, why not weave it into your writing that there are different understandings of the word?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
